# PHP DOM Find Elements Containing A Class

Tags: php, class, domdocument

I'm trying to create and RSS feed of League of Legends news, since they don't have one... I'm trying to parse the HTML and find all elements containing a certain class attribute.

Here is what I have, but it's not finding anything.

```
<?php
    $page = file_get_contents("http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/");
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->load($page);
    $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
    $classname="node-article";
    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($nodes, true) . "</pre>";
?>
```

Edit: Working code...

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents("http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/");
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($page);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname = "node-article";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");

$articles = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $h4 = $node->getElementsByTagName('h4')->item(0);
    $articles[] = array(
        'title' => htmlentities($h4->firstChild->nodeValue),
        'content' => htmlentities($h4->nextSibling->nodeValue),
        'link' => 'http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news' . $h4->firstChild->getAttribute('href')
    );
}

echo "<pre>" . print_r($articles, true) . "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need `loadHTML` (Which reads string containing source) instead of `load` (Which basically accepts path to the document). Also you are using `file_get_contents` which reads entire file into a string. So you already have a string containing HTML Source.

Try this:

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/");
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($page);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname = "node-article";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
echo "<pre>" . print_r($nodes, true) . "</pre>";

// get title and content of article
$arr = array();

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $h4 = $node->getElementsByTagName('h4')->item(0);
    $arr[] = array(
        'title' => $h4->nodeValue,
        'content' => $h4->nextSibling->nodeValue,
    );
}

var_dump($arr); // your title & body content
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. How would I then search the conects of each node for the title/body? `foreach ($nodes as node) { echo "Title: " . $node->query("h4")->nodeValue; }`? Sorry, really struggling with understanding xpath

Comment: @user1960364 Remove just the `query("h4")` part it should work.

Comment: That will get the entire article block, I need to separate out the title and body into different variables to build an RSS feed.

Comment: Awesome, made a few more changes and got it working. Thanks! :D